# PropertyGridControl DevExpress Hide some properties

Tags: devexpress, propertygrid

How can I hide some not virtual properties of parent class in `PropertyGridControl` without using `[Browsable(false)]`? I can not use this, because I can not override not virtual properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot override the property then you can use [`new`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) modifier.
Here is example:

```cs
public class SomeChildClass : SomeParentClass
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    new public TypeOfProperty SomeProperty
    {
        get { return base.SomeProperty; }
        set { base.SomeProperty = value; }
    }
}
```